# Beacon Ranging using ProximityKit framework for Android

Tags: android, ibeacon-android, altbeacon

I'm working on integrating ProximityKit framework into our Android app for detecting beacons we purchased from RadiusNetworks. We wanted the app to be able to range or detect beacons considering three Android app states which are running in foreground, running in background and if app is killed from task switcher (swiped away). As of now, we're utilizing the "didRangeBeaconsInRegion" method from ProximityKit framework to track the logs when beacons are detected. Below are our findings:

1. App is in foreground

   - App is able to range beacons providing a log for each beacon detected 
     every second
   - However, I noticed when in debug mode, the console was showing up lots of similar logs quickly with messages below during beacon ranging which I am thinking could affect the device performance, battery usage and situations when device is getting somehow hot:

`04-20 14:16:17.258 18908-19492/com.droid.mobile.cho D/ScanRecord: first manudata for manu ID
04-20 14:16:17.273 18908-18920/com.droid.mobile.cho D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes`

2. App is in background/minimized

   - App is able to range beacons providing a log for each beacon detected every five minutes in Android N or earlier; however, once every 15 minutes in Android O versions
3. App is killed from task switcher (swiped away)

   - App is NOT able to range beacons (verified by launching a local notification if a beacon is ranged, however no local notification is showing up; tested up to 20 minutes of waiting time)
   - We came up with a solution which is to implement a service running in background handling the proximity kit beacon ranging, however, it would be nice to know if there is a more ideal way of handling this case
   - After implementing the background running service, beacon ranging performs the same as in scenario #1 above
   - I also tried checking the device logs 15 minutes after the app is swiped off from task switcher:

`04-23 10:34:44.449 13220-13220/com.droid.mobile.cho I/BeaconManager: BeaconManager started up on pid 13220 named 'com.droid.mobile.cho' for application package 'com.droid.mobile.cho'.  isMainProcess=true
04-23 10:34:44.452 13220-13220/com.droid.mobile.cho D/BeaconParser: Parsing beacon layout: m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25
04-23 10:48:02.760 13220-13228/com.droid.mobile.cho W/art: Suspending all threads took: 11.608ms
04-23 10:48:52.624 13220-13228/com.droid.mobile.cho W/art: Suspending all threads took: 25.439ms`

- Based from the logs just above, it seems that after almost 15 minutes of the app being killed, all threads were being suspended on the device

For our test devices, we used LG G3 phone running Android OS 5.0.2 and Samsung Galaxy S6 phone running Android OS 7.0.

Considering our above findings, we have our main concerns on the scenarios when the app is killed from task switcher which results to the app not ranging any beacons and the several console logs showing up when app is running in foreground. It would be great if the app can handle all three scenarios when ranging beacons the proper way.

Thank you in advance for the response.

Comment: In the case of swiping the app off the screen with the task switcher, it might be that beacons are being detected but the notification is being blocked by the operating system for some reason.  I'd be curious to know if LogCat shows any sign of the app if followed for 15 minutes after swiping it off the screen.  Of course, the process id will change when the app restarts so you'd have to filter LogCat for a known log pattern from the app, and then go back and filter for the PID you see to try and get more detailed info about what is going on.

Comment: Thanks for the response @davidgyoung..

Comment: I tried to reproduce and copy some logs that I thought are helpful to check any app signs after 15 minutes the app is swiped off from task switcher (please see my edited post above for the logs).

Comment: Those log lines sound like normal garbage collection activity -- I don't think it means the app was suspended, in fact I think it is running normally.  I wonder if upon app restart that ProximityKit is not restarted normally.  You might try logging lines when you application calls `pkManager.start();` and gets callbacks to `didSync()` or `didFailSync()` as well as `didEnterRegion()`, etc.  When troubleshooting auto restarts after killing form the task switcher, verbose logging is your friend.

Comment: David, just wanted to confirm if it is a good workaround to implement a custom background service running ProximityKit methods in order to address the issue when app state is killed from task switcher? I am thinking that ProximityKit framework for Android was made up of Android Beacon library so if that solution will be done, there might be a chance that an existing service from ProximityKit will be running in another custom background service. Please let me know if my assumptions are correct. Thank you.

Comment: A custom background service should be OK, in that under normal conditions it is in the same Android process as the foreground app.  Since the Android Beacon Library's BeaconManager is a singleton, there will be a single instance shared by the background process and the foreground app.  Be careful about Android 8+ though, as it blocks long-running background processes.

Comment: Thanks @davidgyoung for confirming about the solution with regards to implementing custom background service. I re-implemented this solution and configured the custom service with `START_STICKY` so that it will be restarted when app is killed from task switcher. However, an issue I noticed is with regards to phone battery usage when left running for hours.

Comment: It could be because when app is killed from task switcher, it operates the same as when app is running in foreground considering a background service was implemented (Different when app is running in background/minimized as delegate methods are triggered every 5 or 15 minutes depending on Android OS).

Comment: I also tried adding logs on some ProximityKit delegate methods `didSync()` and `didFailSync()` to check if ProximityKit is restarted normally or not when app is killed from task switcher. However, based on my testing, related logs did not show up in console when I did the scenario and waited for at most 20 minutes on it.

Comment: Another concern we wanted to let you know is about deciding whether to migrate from using ProximityKit framework to Android Beacon library or to keep using ProximityKit. We heard some news as well that there is a consideration for stopping support on ProximityKit framework. It would be preferable for us to keep using ProximityKit as we were utilizing Radius Networks portal when setting up beacons and adding up some metadata attributes which were handled by the framework and is necessary for our app use case.

Comment: However, we’re also open to migrating to Android Beacon library if it is the ideal solution considering for long-term cases. It would be great if you could provide your thoughts about it. Thank you @davidgyoung!

Comment: I have no knowledge of plans to discontinue ProximityKit, but I don't work for Radius Networks on a day-to-day basis, so this knowledge does not really mean anything.  The Android Beacon Library is open source and very widely used as of April 2018, so it is very unlikely that the open source community will abandon it soon, even if its lead developer (yours truly) falls off a cliff.

Comment: The funny thing is about your test results is that ProximityKit uses the AndoridBeaconLibrary under the hood.  On Android 4.3.x-7.x, the Android Beacon Library itself uses a BeaconService with a START_STICKY flag.  So it should start up automatically just like your service does.  I would expect that you would see this informational log line:  https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/blob/master/src/main/java/org/altbeacon/beacon/service/BeaconService.java#L211.  You can check your *merged* ApplicationManifest.xml to see if the BeaconService has that flag.

Comment: Thanks for the information you provided @davidgyoung. I was able to see the log you mentioned from your previous comment within our app after the proximityKit manager is started. However, still noticing the app was not able to range beacons when app was killed from task switcher verified through logs and local notifications. I also got a copy of Android ProximityKit reference app from https://github.com/RadiusNetworks/proximitykit-reference-android and observed that the same issue occur in this reference app.

Comment: David, just wondering if you have recommended solutions other than implementing a custom background service as it seems like this is not an ideal one considering mainly the app battery usage (as this will continue to run in the background for a long period of time). Or do you think this is something that can be looked into and be addressed in future releases of ProximityKit framework? Thanks again @davidgyoung for your help and prompt response.

Comment: Your background service should not use CPU if it is sleeping all the time.  Does it do anything?  Sorry, I cannot speak to plans for any future Proximity it releases.  You'd have to ask Radius support.